# App.config .NET Core console application en Linux

Tags: linux, .net, asp.net-core

En Windows para una aplicación de consola utilizo el *App.config*, sección *appSettings* para almacenar algún parámetro de configuración, vea el ejemplo:

```
<Configuration>
   <AppSettings>
     <Add key="param1" value="value1 "/>
     <Add key="param2" value="value2 "/>
   </ AppSettings>
</Configuration>
```

Utilizando .Net Core para una aplicación de consola en Linux, donde guardo la configuración, ¿hay algo parecido a `App.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si existe, se puede usar el nombre que tu quieras para el archivo de configuración pero normalmente es algo así como appsettings.json, la técnica para hacerlo se llama "clases de configuración fuertemente tipadas" lo que implica que tu creas tu clase de configuración como cualquier otra clase y durante el inicio de la aplicación enlazas esta clase contra un archivo json, el cual será creado y mantenido por  .Net core.

Para más información, revisa acá :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fkaduk/2017/02/22/using-strongly-typed-configuration-in-net-core-console-app/

Estoy desde mi celular y me quedaría un poco complicado colocar el código requerido.

Comment: Hola! gracias por tu respuesta, en cuanto puedas podrías agregar algo del código necesario así podemos eliminar el link?

Comment: Si, apenas pueda lo haré.